# python print output piped to BASH leads to "broken pipe"

Tags: python, bash, pipe

I have a `python` script that prints to the stdout a list of files, for example:

`$ ./myscript.py
"file a.txt" "file b.txt" "file c.txt"`

I want to open these files in LESS

`$ less <(./myscript.py)`

But I get the following error:

`-bash: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
$ Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

I think it may be the same problem as @Jon-Clements refers to in
[grep: broken pipe error python 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526428/grep-broken-pipe-error-python-2-2), i.e. the pipe is finished; but I'm not sure.  I also tried (maybe incorrectly) the solution by @chepner [store return value of a Python script in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900828/store-return-value-of-a-python-script-in-a-bash-script) but it gives the same error.

How can I fix this? I know that mixing BASH and Python is bad practice.

BTW, the python script is using a loop around the following statement to produce the list of filenames:

`print('"'+filename+'"',sep=" ",end=' ',)`
Also, when I copy and paste the output manually to `less`, it works fine.

Comment: `the python script is using a loop around the following statement to produce the list of filenames` - Bash can very well do this, and you don't need Python

Comment: the python script is rather more complicated than just that one line: it filters a bigger set of files by content.  I included this snippet because I thought it might need editing

Comment: Can you change the separator between them to null, and remove the quotes? If so you can pipe into xargs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding quotes around the file name isn't helpful. What you *should* do is

1. Output each filename will a null byte between them.
2. Pipe the output to `xargs -0`.

Quoting the filenames won't help unless you somehow use `eval`, which is not a good idea for security reasons. Your command should look something like

```
./myscript.py | xargs -0 less
```

As a hack, if the filenames are simple (i.e. no whitespace, no glob characters), you could modify `./myscript.py` to output just the space-separated file names (no quotes), then run

```
less $(myscript.py)
```

since `less` only takes filename arguments.

Comment: Your solution works.  I have whitespaces in filenames, hence my quoting.  Can you explain 2 things:  Firstly, why does typing  `less "foo bar.txt"`  at the prompt work fine, but a python script returning `"foo bar.txt"` cannot be used in the <($...) way?  Secondly, I thought that quoting was good security, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells

Comment: Quoting is good security, which is why `less $(myscript.py)` is only safe if you know that the files returned by `myscript.py` won't be changed by word-splitting or pathname expansion. When `less "foo.txt"` is processed by the shell, it removes the syntactic quotes before passing the string `foo.txt` to `less`. When the quotes are part of a parameter expansion, though, such as `f='"foo.txt"'; less $foo` (or `less "$foo"` in this case), the quotes are literal characters in the value of the parameter, and *not* subject to quote removal.